# How to get Intent Data from Activity into Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

This is my MainActivity from which I am passing my data to the other Recipient Fragment class

```
Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent(this, RecipientsActivity.class);
            recipientsIntent.setData(mMediaUri);

            String fileType;
            if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST) {
                fileType = ParseConstants.TYPE_IMAGE;
            }
            else {
                fileType = ParseConstants.TYPE_VIDEO;
            }

            recipientsIntent.putExtra(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE, fileType);
            startActivity(recipientsIntent);
```

I have called this intent into my Recipients.class Fragment

```
mMediaUri = getActivity().getIntent().getData();
        mFileType = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE);
```

This has given me an error for Class Cast Exception on Recipients.class Fragment.

Comment: How do you create the fragment?

Comment: @slanecek I don't get your question. You want to know how I created my fragment?

Comment: Exactly. How do you do it?

Answer (score 1):

From Activity you send data with intent as:

```
        Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent(this, RecipientsActivity.class);
        recipientsIntent.setData(mMediaUri);

        String fileType;
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST) {
            fileType = ParseConstants.TYPE_IMAGE;
        }
        else {
            fileType = ParseConstants.TYPE_VIDEO;
        }

        recipientsIntent.putExtra(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE, fileType);


        // set Fragmentclass Arguments
        Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
        fragobj.setArguments(recipientsIntent );
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
public class Fragmentclass extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String mFileType = getArguments().getString(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE);    

}
}
```

Comment: how to go about with the MediaUri?

Comment: How to go about with passing Uri to the Fragment I have mediauri in my code. and How to start fragment after passing the args.